# Is it possible to setup github pull requests to use rebase instead of merge?

Tags: github

When I create a pull request on Github, it gives me a nice 'Merge' button on the pull request page. Is it possible to configure this button to do a rebase instead of a merge?

Answer (score 0):

No, it always does a `git merge --no-ff`, and the github website doesn't have access to your local configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It may be interesting to note, despite the question being ages old, that Github finally added this option!

The whole story is here:
https://github.com/blog/2243-rebase-and-merge-pull-requests

Keep in mind that this option does change your commits, setting the committer to the current user. Also the commit date changes. Thus, the commit hashes change.